# Having issues with connecting mini elecret microphone to the Pi

Tags: microphone

We have set up the ADS1015 on the Pi 3B+. When typing in "i2cdetect -y 1" this seems to work just fine. However, we have looked up every single tutorial on the internet, and we can't find any proper way to connect our mini electret microphone.

This is the microphone we have:

https://ibb.co/KW9gYY6

Eventually we want this microphone to collect sound and turn this sound into vibration. However we have no clue how to connect this microphone to our Pi.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  You need to connect the microphone to the ADC.  That is a problem in signal conditioning.  Perhaps try an electronics site.

Comment: You need an amplifier for the mic also (and I suspect what you really want is a sound card not an ADC).

Comment: Amplifying microphone signals was already discussed in details on EE.SE ([example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359635/connect-microphone-with-pre-amp-to-stm32-adc)). Either buy a sound amplifier, or make sure you understand how to make your own. And Tomas is right: standalone ADCs can be used to measure signal amplitude, but if you want to also measure the frequency, consider using a sound card.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network.
Does it have to be a discrete microphone like that Electret unit you have there?  Have you considered a cheap USB audio adapter - they typically have a stereo audio output but they also can have a (mono) microphone input to which you can attach a cheap microphone with a 3.5mm jack plug...